# flask integration with mysqldb

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I am new to flask framework. I want to connect with a MySQL database

[image]

[image]

and my code in the `__init__.py` is

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)  
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate =Migrate(app,db)
```

but I am getting this error

> Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
>   sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError:
>   (mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError) Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/tw8g)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi there!
Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the following requirement using pip:

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

I perform my MySQL connection with Flask using similar code (tested now):

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'youruser'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'yourpassword'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'yourdb'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'yourhost'
mysql = MySQL(app)
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello_db():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor =conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * from yourtable''')
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return str(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Please change the variables with your data (user/password etc) and try the connection.